# How to numpy concatenate two arrays with different dimensions

Tags: numpy, concatenation

I am trying to numpy concatenate an image shaped 25 by 25 with another array shaped (3,). However, whenever I do it, the combined shapes become a dimension of (2,). I want the dimensions of the images with the dimension of the other array so it will become 25,25,3. Are there any suggestions?

Here is the code

```
a = np.ones(1)
combine =  ((x,y), (h,w), a)
b = (images, combine)
c = np.concatenate([b])
```

I tried to do `np.concatenate([images, combine])` but that returns a separate error.

Comment: A (25,25,3) array is 3x larger than a (25,25) one, and 625x larger than a (3,).  Your proposed concatenation doesn't make much sense.  Maybe `concatenate` is the wrong term.

Comment: With `concatenate` you can join a (25,25) array with a (25,3) to make a (25,28).  Or do something similar with rows.  Or join one (25,25) with another to make a (2,25,25) or even (25,25,2).  To make a (25,25,3) you need to join 3 (25,25) arrays (or replicate the values of one 3 times).

Comment: Look at [np.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy-stack)

Comment: What are `x`,`y` etc?  numbers?  `combine` is then a tuple with 3 elements. Not an array. And if wrapped in `np.array` it's (3,) shape, object dtype.  How do you expect to combine that with a (25,25) numeric array?  May be more to the point, what do you hope to do with the result?